# Gigabit Ethernet: capacitor isolation (1st device) - transformer isoaltion (2nd device) will it work?

Tags: ethernet, emc, interface, high-speed

I am designing an adapter board for a camera which is an original device with Gigabit Ethernet interface.

The previous version of the adapter board was using LAN7500 and transformer as a USB dongle but now I have to replace it with LAN7800 (LAN7500 is not available on the market).

The main difference is that LAN7800 is supporting capacitor isolation instead use of a transformer. My concern is if there will be any problems if the adapter will use capacitors for isolation and the camera will stay with the transformer? The adapter and camera have a common GND (through power supply).

Or there have to be transformers on both sides? I am not able to verify the transceiver model on the camera.

I will be grateful for any suggestions because the topic of Ethernet is new to me.

Comment: why do you want to use capacitive isolation?

Comment: Where are you seeing this? The Ethernet standard specifies the magnetic for isolation, and capacitive isolation doesn't even make sense for this type of part.

Answer (score 1):

The [EVB-LAN7800](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/UNG8000_EVB_LAN7800_A1-sch.pdf) USB adaptor does use transformers for galvanic isolation. The magnetics are designed into the MDI connector.

If you are designing your own adapter, suggested magnetics are [provided](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN8.13-Application-Note-DS00003016A.pdf)

The use of serial capacitors rather than transformer isolation is typically only used for PCB backplane communication applications, not externally connected cable applications where immunity protection is more important.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the cable connection between the camera and adapter is circa 3 cm (with twisted wires).